# @Query - You have an error in your SQL syntax error

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have an `Employee` entity class that has many columns. I want to get some columns from this class. So I created a new `EmployeeSalaries` class and wrote query in `EmployeeRepository`. When I make a request to `getEmployeeWithSalariesById` from swagger I get this error:

```
2022-02-25 23:47:17.214 ERROR 28705 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as col_6_0_ from employees employee0_ inner join salaries salaries1_ on employee' at line 1
2022-02-25 23:47:17.247 ERROR 28705 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
```

My Employee class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "emp_no")
    private  int id;
    @Column(name = "birth_date")   
    private Date birthDate;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private char gender;
    @Column(name = "hire_date")  
    private Date hireDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employees")
    private List<Title> titles; 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employees")
    private List<Salary> salaries;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    private List<DeptEmp> departmentList;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
   private List<DeptManager> managerDepartment;

}
```

My Salary class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "salaries")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler","employees"})
public class Salary {

    @Column(name = "salary")
    private int salary;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "from_date")
    private Date fromDate;
    @Column(name = "to_date")
    private Date toDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "emp_no")
    private Employee employees;
}
```

and EmployeeSalaries class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeSalaries {
    
    private  int id;
    private Date birthDate;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private char gender;
    private Date hireDate;
    private Collection<Salary> salaries;

}
```

@Query in Employee Repository:

```
@Query("Select new dev.serhat.employeeapi.models.dtos.EmployeeSalaries"
    + "(e.id, e.birthDate, e.firstName, e.lastName, e.gender, e.hireDate, e.salaries) From Employee e Where e.id= :id")
    Optional<EmployeeSalaries> getEmployeeWithSalariesById(int id);
```

Comment: Jpa select ettiğin kolonları direk olarak EmployeeSalaries class'ına map edemez. Bunun için interface projectionları var https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections veya verileri çekip servis sınıfında EmployeeSalaries dto'sunun içini doldurabilirsin

Comment: @isadev41 cevap için teşekür ederim. Çok uzun ve fazla ilişkisi bulunan entity sınıflarının  sadece istediğimiz sütunlarını çekmek istediğimizde hangi yöntemleri kullanmak daha iyi olur. Yeni öğrenmeye başladım :) Dto bunun çözümlerinden biri sanırım. Aynı tablo için birden fazla farklı entity sınıfı oluştumak doğru olur mu? (Ben tüm ilişkileri içeren tek employee sınıfı oluşturdum. Employee'nin title ya da salary ilişkilerini bölerek farklı entity sınıfları oluşturmak gibi). Bu konuyla ilgili bildiğin açıklayıcı yazı ya da tutorial varsa paylaşabilirmisin?

Comment: farklı entity sınıflarına ayırmak sana kalmış, ayırırsan daha iyi olur diye düşünüyorum. Tablolarının boyutları çok büyümemiş olur. Çok uzun ve fazla ilişki bulanan entitylerde sorgu yaparken, tek bir sorgu yazıp, bu sorguya uygun attığım linkteki gibi projection oluşturup daha sonra dto'yu doldurabilirsin. Veya direk böldüğün entity sınıflarına özel ayrı ayrı sorgular atıp bu sorguların sonuçlarını servis katmanında dto üzerinde birleştirebilirsin. Bunun için native query veya HQL query kullanabilirsin. Sorgularını optimize etmek için de best practiceleri inceleyebilirsin diye düşünüyorum.

Comment: şuradaki blog yazıları yardımcı olabilir https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data
- https://www.baeldung.com/persistence-with-spring-series